How to Save a Matrix as a PNG Image and Reload it to Recover the Original Matrix
I would like to save a 96x96 matrix as an image.
The values in the matrix range from -1 to 1.
When I save the matrix using
plt.imsave(path, matrix, cmap='rainbow'),

it gets stored as a 96x96x4 RGBA image, and each channel's values are rescaled to the 0–255 range.
This makes it difficult to retrieve the original values of the matrix.
Is there a way to preserve the original matrix values when saving and reloading the image?
I attempted the following approach to retrieve the original matrix:
loaded_image = plt.imread(path)
restored_image = np.mean(loaded_image[:, :, :3], axis=2)
print(restored_image )

However, this method only reproduces a matrix with the same dimensions as the original matrix, but the values differ from those of the original matrix.

Well, you lose information about the original range when you save the matrix to an image. Maybe you could just save the matrix itself? If you really need to convert an image back to a matrix, you need the original min/max, and an inverse function as described in How to decode color mapping.

There is not a single good answer to your question, as it is not quite clear to me why you want to save your matrix as an image in the first place. Consider the following: Most images that are used in standard use cases (think of showing pictures online, creating plots of data, etc.) are 8-bit RGB(A) or grayscale images, meaning you have 3 or 4 channels for RGB (red, green, blue, and maybe opacity) or 1 channel for grayscale (intensity), each storing 256 integer values (0 to 255). Your data, on the other hand, is floating point data in a very different range (-1 to 1). So a standard, 8-bit image may not be the ideal medium to store your matrix.
There are multiple options you could choose from, depending on the actual task that you are trying to solve:

Since you seem to work with Numpy, you might consider storing your data directly as a Numpy array – have a look at numpy.save() and numpy.load() for that.
If you want to store your data in a Numpy-independent format, you could even consider storing it as a text file, given your matrix only contains 96×96 values – have a look at numpy.savetxt() and numpy.loadtxt() for that. There are other, more advanced formats for storing array data in a language-agnostic way, e.g. HDF5, but I guess that would be a bit too much here.
If you really want to store your matrix as an image, but with minimum loss of information, you could consider using a bit of a less standard image format, such as floating-point TIFF. The tifffile library should support this.
Finally, if you want to use a "standard" (8-bit) image, you need to normalize your image data before saving (convert from [-1, 1] to [0, 255]) and after loading (convert from [0, 255] to [-1, 1]). You will lose precision there though, as already mentioned. The following code achieves this, for example:
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0xC0FFEE)

# Produce some exemplary data in the given range
mat = rand.uniform(low=-1., high=1., size=(96, 96))
# Move to range [0, 255], then convert to integers
mat_uint8 = np.round((255 / 2) * (mat + 1)).astype(np.uint8)
# Save as 8-bit PNG image
Image.fromarray(mat_uint8).save("matrix.png")
# Load and reconstruct original matrix
mat_rec = np.asarray(Image.open("matrix.png")).astype(float) * (2 / 255) - 1
assert(np.allclose(mat, mat_rec, atol=1e-2))
print(f"Max. abs. difference: {np.abs(mat_rec - mat).max():.5f}")
# Prints 0.00392




Thank you for your kind response.
I want to clarify that I'm trying to save the matrix as a PNG image to use as input for an image model (like DDPM). For my task, I need to convert the image back to the matrix to check how closely the DDPM-generated images match the original matrix.
I appreciate your various suggestions, especially since I didn't provide a clear reason. My matrix will always have decimal values in the range of -1 to 1. If I convert it to [0, 255] for an 8-bit image, will it be difficult to revert it back to the original values?

@김요한 You're welcome. As to your last question, not sure if I understand correctly: What do you mean by difficult? In the sense of code, it's not difficult: use np.asarray(Image.open("matrix.png")).astype(float) * (2 / 255) - 1 (load the image, and convert values back from [0, 255] to [-1, 1]), as given in my answer. But, as I also mentioned, since you stored your values in 8-bit int, while your original values are floats, you will not be able to restore your original values perfectly due to rounding error. So, in the latter sense, it's impossible to restore the (exact) original values.

Another side note: You mentioned you need to feed your data to an ML image model. Also in that case, you probably don't need to go the way via images, but you might also be able to use your original data. You might need to adjust your model infrastructure a bit to achieve this; with PyTorch, for example, you might need to provide your own Dataset instance for being able to load your original data directly.

By "difficult," I meant to ask whether perfect restoration was impossible.
I understand now, thank you very much.
I'll try various approaches based on your comments.

First of all, if you only need to store and retrieve a matrix you can use numpy.save or numpy.savetxt directly on the matrix [1],[2]. If you do want to have an image, for debugging or whatever neat purpose, without sacrificing too much precision you can save it to a 16-bit PNG using imageio and reload the image. In my tests precision is in the order of 1E-4.
See the snippet below for an example:
import imageio
import numpy as np

INT16_MAX = 2**15 - 1

path = 'test.png'

vmin = -1
vmax = 1

matrix = (vmax - vmin) * np.random.rand(96, 96) + vmin # generate a random matrix of size 96x96 with values between -1 and 1

# Transform to int16 range, write to 16bit PNG
matrix_i = (matrix - vmin) / (vmax - vmin) * INT16_MAX # transform the matrix to the range [0, 2^16 - 1]
imageio.imwrite(path, matrix_i.astype(np.int16))

# Load image and transform back to original range
loaded_image = imageio.imread(path).astype(np.float64)
restored_image = (vmax - vmin) * np.array(loaded_image) / INT16_MAX + vmin

print(f"maximum error is {np.max(np.abs(restored_image - matrix))}.")

Limitation is you have to know your data range in terms of vmin and vmax a priori. So unless you have a good reason, I would still store the matrix to binary or text format directly.

Thank you for your kind response.
I want to clarify that I'm trying to save the matrix as a PNG image to use as input for an image model (like DDPM). For my task, I need to convert the image back to the matrix to check how closely the DDPM-generated images match the original matrix.
I appreciate your various suggestions, especially since I didn't provide a clear reason. My matrix will always have decimal values in the range of -1 to 1. If I convert it to [0, 255] for an 8-bit image, will it be difficult to revert it back to the original values?

Depending on your application the quantization to 8bit might be too coarse. Especially, when you compare a model output keep in mind the quantization error. 2/256 is in the order of 1E-2. @simon explained it well in his comment, so I won't repeat.
